# Capture inserted rows and return to the client application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I basically need to capture ids of inserted rows and return it to angular application. The code below is from asp.net web api application. I have declared  an integer array

int[] documentIds = null .

mgrDocument contains the id after execution of

```
mgrDocument = mgrDocumentService.Create(mgrDocument);
```

How do I add that value to the integer array and return it via the webapi. I have a foreach loop hence dont have the index otherwise I would have done

documentIds[index] = mgrDocument.ID;

Once all the ids are retrieved , I need to send it to the client to query those ids. How do I then return those ids.

web api

```
  [HttpPost]
        [SkipTokenAuthorization]
        [Route("api/documentupload/create")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Create(DocumentUploadCreateViewModel model)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            var mgrStrategyDocument = new MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT();
            var mgrDocumentService = GetService<DOCUMENT>();
            var mgrStrategyDocumentService = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT>();
            int[] documentIds = null;

            if (model != null)
            {
                foreach (var obj in model.DocumentDetails)
                {
                    var mgrDocument = new DOCUMENT
                    {
                        DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID = obj.DocumentTypeId,
                        DOCUMENT_DATE = obj.DocumentDate,
                        NAME = obj.Name,
                        DOCUMENT_CONTENT = convertByteArray(obj.file),
                        EXTENSION = GetFileExtension(obj.Name)
                };
                    mgrDocument = mgrDocumentService.Create(mgrDocument);
                    documentIds[obj] = mgrDocument.ID;

                    var mangerStrategyDocumentService = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT>();
                    var mgrStrategyDocument1 = new MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT()
                    {
                        DOCUMENT_ID = mgrDocument.ID,
                        MANAGERSTRATEGY_ID = model.ManagerStrategyId

                    };
                    mgrStrategyDocument = mgrStrategyDocumentService.Create(mgrStrategyDocument1);

                }
               return  response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mgrStrategyDocument);
            }
           return null;

        }
```

This is what the MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT looks like

```
{Permal.BSG.Manager.Core.Model.MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT}
    CREATED_BY_ID: 0
    DATE_CREATED: {07/07/2019 08:01:17}
    DOCUMENT: {Permal.BSG.Manager.Core.Model.DOCUMENT}
    DOCUMENT_ID: 590834
    ID: 186423
    LAST_MODIFIED: {07/07/2019 08:01:17}
    LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID: 0
    MANAGERSTRATEGY_ID: 7079
    ManagerStrategy: null
```

Comment: Don't know; what would your client like the returned data to look like?

Comment: Hi caucius, I need to return ids only in this call. I will then make a second call of another endpoint with these ids

Comment: What does the managerstrategy document look like? it looks like you're returning it; how about adding a representation of the ids into it?

Comment: Yes I am returning it but not used it yet. It’s an usual object with values

Comment: I have updated the post to show what  MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT looks like

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by implementint return type of List

```
 [HttpPost]
        [SkipTokenAuthorization]
        [Route("api/documentupload/create")]
        public List<int> Create(DocumentUploadCreateViewModel model)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            var mgrStrategyDocument = new MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT();
            var mgrDocumentService = GetService<DOCUMENT>();
            var mgrStrategyDocumentService = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT>();
            List<int> documentIds = new List<int>();


            if (model != null)
            {
                foreach (var obj in model.DocumentDetails)
                {
                    var mgrDocument = new DOCUMENT
                    {
                        DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID = obj.DocumentTypeId,
                        DOCUMENT_DATE = obj.DocumentDate,
                        NAME = obj.Name,
                        DOCUMENT_CONTENT = convertByteArray(obj.file),
                        EXTENSION = GetFileExtension(obj.Name)
                };
                    mgrDocument = mgrDocumentService.Create(mgrDocument);
                    documentIds.Add(mgrDocument.ID);
                    var mangerStrategyDocumentService = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT>();
                    var mgrStrategyDocument1 = new MANAGERSTRATEGY_DOCUMENT()
                    {
                        DOCUMENT_ID = mgrDocument.ID,
                        MANAGERSTRATEGY_ID = model.ManagerStrategyId

                    };
                    mgrStrategyDocument = mgrStrategyDocumentService.Create(mgrStrategyDocument1);

                }

                return documentIds;
                //return  response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mgrStrategyDocument);
            }
           return null;

        }
```